# Task based async vs async with callback

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was porting this old code from .NET to .NET Core where a web service is consumed and async callbacks are implemented to consume the service.

With .NETCore's WCF web service reference provider only creates methods for task based async.

My questions are:

1. Does .NETCore not support async callbacks for web service?
2. What is the difference between task based async vs async with callback?

Comment: Note that async callbacks are just event-based asynchronous programming. There is nothing special about them, unlike with Tasks

Comment: How are you generating your classes for the web service. Please update your question with step by step instructions saying what you did.

Comment: Also, here is some documentation showing how to convert from [Task based async to async callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#TapToApm)

Answer (score 2):

Async callbacks (Ex. `BeginRequest()`) and Async/Await (Ex `await BeginRequestAsync()`) are functionally the same and differ only in how you structure your code to use the async functionality.

Async callbacks were the only way you could do async programming with C# <5.0. In 5.0 Async/Await were introduced and are the preferred way for doing async programming but many old APIs were kept as-is with callback methods for backwards compatibility.

With .Net Core, there is C# 6.0 support from version 1.0. Since async/await is the preferred design pattern for handling async code there is no benefit for implementing async callbacks.

Comment: "With .Net Core, there is C# 6.0 support from version 1.0", only because .NET Core got support in VS2015 which was the first to receive c# 6.0 support. They are unrelated